# Measuring the HSE frequency of an STM32F2

Tags: clock, stm32

I am programming an STM32F2 (manual [here](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00225773.pdf)). I am having clock problems and would like to check every clock using an oscilloscope. The first clock I want to check is HSE, which stands for: High Speed External (Clock).

How can I use an oscilloscope to measure the HSE frequency of my chip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what HSE is, but it shouldn't matter (if it does, you need to add relevant information to your question).

A oscilloscope displays voltage as a function of time.  Capture a single cycle or known multiples of cycles and measure the elapsed time on the X axis.  Divide the number of cycles by that time and you you get the frequency.  Yes, it really is that easy.

It can be even easier.  Even low end digital scopes have a frequency counter function built in.  These usually work off the trigger pulses, so you have to set up the scope to trigger on each cycle.  The scope then shows you directly what the frequency is.  This probably won't work though if the signal is irregular.

A better answer will require a better question.

Comment: I'm looking a something more specific. HSE means High Speed External (Clock). I want to know to what pins I should attach my oscilloscope. Normally all that information should be in the (linked) manual, but I cannot find the information.

Comment: @Randomblue you should know where the clock of your microcontroller is

Comment: @Random: Surely the datasheet for the microcontroller shows you what all the pins are, including the clock pins.  I simply don't believe this information is not there.  Look harder.

Comment: The HSE pins are clearly marked OSC_OUT and OSC_IN.

Read the actual chip datasheet instead of the family programming manual...

Comment: @dext0rb: No. OSC_OUT and OSC_IN are if you set an *external* HSE clock. The appropriate pins, I later found out, are MCO1 and MCO2, properly configured to output HSE.

Comment: @Randomblue HSE is external by definition, hence "E". If you want to measure internal clock that would be HSI. Your question is about external clock, so this answer is correct. You can use MCO (master clock output) pins to measure various internal frequencies after PLL and dividers, but that wouldn't be "HSE frequency" as asked.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but i will provide an answer for it, cause i was also looking for it.

STM2Fxx provides a handy way of outputting SYSTEM, HSI, HSE or PLL clock signal on specialized pins called MCO1 and MCO2. Here is the example code of how to configure it

```
RCC->PLLCFGR     = (16<<0) | (200<< 6) | (2<<24);  //Set pll clock to 100MHz
RCC->CFGR       |= (7<<24) | (3<<21);              //MCO1 uses PLL output and devides it byt 7
RCC->CR         |= (1<<24);                        //Enables PLL
RCC->AHB1ENR    |= (1<<0);                         //Enables clock on GPIOA port
GPIOA->MODER    |= (2<<16);                        //Sets pin PA8 to alternating function which is by default MCO1 outoput.
```

The breakdown, configure your PLL clock before enabling it, configure MCO1 source and prescaler, enable PLL clock, enable clock on GPIOA and set pin PA8 to alternate function this will automatically make it output MCO1 clock signal due to default reset value of alternate function register since MCO1 function is 0.

Note: according to my datasheet, MCO1 can use HSI, HSE, or PLL as a source, however MCO2 can also output system clock which i use to profile my mcu.

This examples uses STM32F746NG microcontroller

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need in our project, where we were using HAL with an STM32F7 processor.

In our case, to get the HSE out on PA8, we just called the function:

```
HAL_RCC_MCOConfig(RCC_MCO1, RCC_MCO1SOURCE_HSE, RCC_MCODIV_1);
```

For our processor, the function is described on Page 725 of the HAL manual UM1905.

[image: UM1905 - Description of STM32F7 HAL and low-layer drivers, page 725]

You are on the right track using a clock-out pin to buffer the clock. Measuring directly on the crystal is no good because the frequency is influenced by the load capacitance and, once you put the probe on the pin, you load the crystal with additional 1pF ~ 15pF, depending on the probe. That is enough to throw your frequency way off. The buffered clock is what the MCU really sees, and the MCOs allow you to measure internal frequencies as well.