# Keil watch window and clock of STM32f103

Tags: stm32, keil

Here is my public variable definition and value:

[image]

[image]

As you can see in this picture I can't track the value of the Hello variable:

[image]

I have changed the position of the Hello variable to prevent it from being constant during the execution time.

[image]

It still has two problems in debug mode (the data-type is different, "Cannot evaluate" error"). In addition, the break-points option is disabled in debug mode.

[image]

In addition, I need to know that the frequency of my MCU has been changed correctly to 72 MHz.

```
RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);

FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_0);

RCC_PLLCmd(DISABLE);
RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSE_Div1,9);
RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);

while(RCC_GetFlagStatus( RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY)!=SET);

FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);

RCC_ClockSecuritySystemCmd(ENABLE);
RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);
RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);

while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08);
SystemCoreClockUpdate();
```

Comment: In all likelihood the value you're putting into `Hello` and probably the entire variable itself are being optimized away by your compiler because you never use it anywhere. Try changing the `while(1)` to `while(Hello)` instead to fool the compiler into thinking that the value and variable are being used.

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint at the line where you write the clksource to the variable and go single stepping from there. Can you see the value then?

Comment: Also... why is Keil marking so many things red? Did you check what error there is?

Comment: Thank you, I have done what you said to me. I have updated my post to check my Keil operation. In addition, the lines which are red are compiled correctly and before debugging they have no color.

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you could upload the whole main.c file. Then I could look for the problem more easily ;)

Comment: I really appreciate your kindness , https://filebin.net/gwfwxdl9ja6tg9sc/5.zip?t=6fzwyw3j

Comment: Unfortunatly I can not find anything obvious, it seems to work for me (although I don't have an STM32F here, so I ported the code to an STM32L4. Are you sure the code compiled without errors? Or maybe delete the variable from the watch-window and add it again.

Comment: Thank you Jusaca for your time and help. It seems it has problem with STM32f103 because it works fine in other MCU even STM32f107.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Looks like there is a name conflict.

Comment: shouldnt be a problem, it will just cast it

Comment: Thank you for your help. But the type is fixed I can't changed (uchar is not changable)

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have osiloscope nearby you can measure your system clock on MCO2 pin of your microcontroller. [Measuring the HSE frequency of an STM32F2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28477/measuring-the-hse-frequency-of-an-stm32f2/482754#482754), here is answer on how to set it up and measure your clock externaly.

You second option to measure system clock is by using internal timers.

Regarding your PLL configuration, you dont need to wait for it to become ready. according to datasheet mcu will automatically switch to it once it is ready if you just enble it and set it as a system clock source.

Now regarding watching data, you have declared it as a global variable, so it will have a constant address. hover over your variable during debugging and it will show the address. copy this address to watch expression and you can view its value.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Unfortunatly in this project I haven't access to MOC pins based on my PCB design(they are free and close to other pins).

Comment: @Parisa then your only option is to utilize RTC (Real time clock) which is a very precise low speed clock. you can mesure how many nop instruction you would do per second.  and based on that you can calculate your clock speed.

Comment: @Parisa  example. get value stored in RTC seconds register. run a for loop with 1M nop instructions. read RTC seconds register again and calculate (including nops and compqares and branches) how many seconds it took for given clock cycles and then it is a simple math :)